# Link target out of date

Tags: facebook, caching

Apparently FB caches link targets and I cannot find a way to force it to update. I used the debug tool at:   https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to test www.rideofthepatriots.com. The scrapped URL show a version of the page that existed five years ago.

How can I force it to update.

Answer (score 1):

Your meta description is exactly that. I guess facebook is getting the data from it.

```
<meta content="As many as three thousand motorcycles are expected for Patriot Harley-Davidson's 9th Annual Ride of the Patriots, the dealership's Memorial Day Weekend caravan of bikers paying tribute to and raising awareness of American POWs, MIA soldiers, and veterans of war. After assembling at the dealership on Sunday, May 28th, the parade of bikers will follow a route to the Pentagon where it will join with as many as three hundred and fifty thousand other bikers from around the country before beginning a final, massive parade of bikes headed to the Mall and the Vietnam Veterans' Memorial in DC." name="description">
```

I suggest you fix those also:

```
Inferred Property   The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property   The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property   The og:description property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property   The og:image property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

Comment: Interesting, but I don't see how that updates the version cached.